# cp: invalid option -- '/'

Tags: coreutils

I am trying to recover my encrypted folder by using ubuntu live cd, I have done all the steps now all I want to do is to copy my `/tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG` to `/home/ubuntu/myfolder` directory.

I am using this command:

```
cp -Rv/tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG/home/ubuntu/myfolder
```

but then I am getting this error `cp: invalid option -- '/'`.

Please help me out how to copy data of `/tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG` to my `/home/ubuntu/myfolder`.

Comment: I you want to copy  /tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG to  /home/ubuntu/myfolder , use  `cp -Rv /tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG /home/ubuntu/myfolder`

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @Braiam While that reasoning applies well in situations where the typo is uncommon, leaving out a space between arguments to a commonly used command is probably a frequently encountered error. I've seen other people have this problem (with the `cp` command, even) and I've made this mistake myself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have forgot to put a space between your options and your path as well as the source path and the destination path. Your statement should look like this.

```
cp -Rv /tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG /home/ubuntu/myfolder
```

Depending on how you decrypted the folder, you might need root permissions to complete the copy. That would make the command look like this.

```
sudo cp -Rv /tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG /home/ubuntu/myfolder
```

That being said, based on your post I would be very cautious about what you are trying to do. The Live CD version of Ubuntu runs in memory and might not have enough space to hold the files stored in your encrypted folder. Even if it does, you could lose all those files as soon as you reboot (the only possible exception being a Live USB with a persistence file). A much better idea would be to copy the files to some sort of external storage for safekeeping.

Comment: ok I can delete now

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't know why I was having so much trouble... lol

Comment: cp: cannot access ‘/tmp/ecryptfs.bM59alvG’: Permission denied

Comment: now i am getting this error

Comment: are you user of that home account user ?

Comment: ...because probably you do not have permission to copy it. But this is a different question... I warmly advise you to read (all of) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-getting-started.htm